# Typescript not detecting global "gtag" variable declared by the package @types/gtag.js

Tags: typescript, tsconfig, gtag.js, .d.ts

Typescript is not being able to detect my global `gtag` var.

I have the `@types/gtag.js` installed. Here is its `index.d.ts` file:

**node_modules/@types/gtag.js/index.d.ts**

[image]

This is the error I was getting:

[image]

So I added this to my `.eslintrc.js`

```
globals: {
  gtag: typeof gtag   // IT DOES DETECT THE gtag TYPE HERE
},
```

Now I'm getting only this error:

[image]

> Cannot find name 'gtag'.

Here is my `tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": false,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "types": [
      "node"
    ],
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@app/*": [
        "./app/*"
      ],
      "@lib/*": [
        "./lib/*"
      ]
    },
  },
  "include": [
    "next-env.d.ts",
    "**/*.ts",
    "**/*.tsx"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

What can I do to make Typescript detect the declared `gtag` global variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My problem was related to the `types` property on the `tsconfig.json`

**tsconfig.json**

```
//  "types": [
//    "node"
//  ],
```

Once I've removed those lines, the global `gtag` type was detected.

From https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#types

[image]